# How to avoid repeating dll dependency in two projects under the same solution

Tags: c#, mysql.data

**THE SETUP**

I have two C# projects under the same solution:

```
ProjectA
ProjectB
```

`ProjectA` has a reference pointing to `ProjectB`.

`ProjectB` contains a reference to the MySql.Data ADO.Net driver, which means that `app.config` needs these lines of configuration:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

**THE PROBLEM**

When I do a mysql operation, `ProjectA` calls `ProjectB`. Then `ProjectB` calls `MySql.Data`. But the `app.config` being used is the one from `ProjectA` (the startup project).

So if I want to be able to both:

1. Test `ProjectB` alone
2. Test the interaction between `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`

...do I need to have `MySql.Data` referenced in both projects and also have the same `<DbProviderFactories>` repeated in both? (the `app.config` problem could be solved by using a reference to the same one in both projects, but the `MySql.Data` dependency is what bothers me the most).

Am I doing something wrong? / Is there any way to simplify things?

Thanks.

Comment: Project's are independent of each others references and referencing a project from another project will only reference the referenced project's namespaces and members, not any of the imported references it have. In short you do have to reference the library from both projects. At least to my knowledge unless there is some special settings in Visual Studio that magically will reference libraries, but I don't think so.

Comment: OK. I was hoping that there was a way in which Visual Studio somehow was aware that if `A` uses `B`, and `B` uses `C`, then a call from `A` to `B` would implicitly include all the necessary stuff for `B` to use `C`. Which I guess comes down to: "every time there is an action taken by `B`, it uses its own `app.config` and not the one from the startup project". But if that can not be done then... it is what it is.

Comment: If projectB has dependency X and projectB exposes any type from X, then projectA has to reference dependency X as well. if projectB hides any used  types from X then projectA doesn't have to reference X

Comment: @RamiYampolsky `ProjectB` hides any used types from X. But is using some info defined at startup (`<DbProviderFactories>` and such). Since `ProjectB` is not the startup project, it is not loading this info correctly. Thus the only workaround I found was referencing the same dll twice and setting the `<DbProviderFactories>` twice in each app.config, so I can use both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` as startup projects and still load the dependency correctly.

Comment: can you wrap the "startup code" that required by ProjectB in some static method in this project and in the startup function of projectA just call this method?

Comment: the thing is that there is not such startup code, it all happens behind the scenes... (at least at my knowledge level). The `MySql.Data` is called internally via `app.config`, and I think I would find it very hard to find a workaround for that ...